# Custom TLabel not displaying on FinishedPage in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I must be missing something obvious here. I'm trying to add a link to the release notes onto `wpFinished` but can't seem to make it show up:

I have a file `finishedPage.iss` which I include via `#include "InnoDialogs\finishedPage.iss";`
The file has the following content:

```pascal
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\bin\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; \
    Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilen

[Code]
{ procedures to deal with page interaction }
procedure ReleaseNotesClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    errorCode: Integer;
begin
    ShellExec('','https://myUrl.com/Release_Notes', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, errorCode)
end;

{ build the page }
procedure FinishedPage_Create;
var
    ReleaseNotesLink: TLabel;

begin

    ReleaseNotesLink := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
    ReleaseNotesLink.Parent := WizardForm.FinishedPage;
    ReleaseNotesLink.Caption := 'Read the Releasenotes';
    ReleaseNotesLink.Enabled := True;
    ReleaseNotesLink.Visible := True;
    ReleaseNotesLink.AutoSize := True;
    ReleaseNotesLink.Left := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Left;
    ReleaseNotesLink.Top := WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Top + ScaleY(100);
    ReleaseNotesLink.OnClick := @ReleaseNotesClick;
    ReleaseNotesLink.ParentFont := True;
    ReleaseNotesLink.Font.Style := ReleaseNotesLink.Font.Style + [fsUnderline, fsBold];
    ReleaseNotesLink.Font.Color := clBlue;
    ReleaseNotesLink.Cursor := crHand;

end;
```

In the `CurPageChanged` procedure in my main installer file I have:

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
    if CurPageID = wpFinished then
        begin
            FinishedPage_Create();
        end;
end;
```

This compiles just fine, but I can't make it show up. I tried different positions as well, thinking perhaps it's just drawn behind something else. I'm using the same procedure for adding elements to other pages...

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your label is hidden behind the `RunList`, which occupies the rest of the page.

You have to shrink the list. For example:

```pascal
WizardForm.RunList.Height := ScaleY(24);

ReleaseNotesLink.Left := WizardForm.RunList.Left;
ReleaseNotesLink.Top := WizardForm.RunList.Top + WizardForm.RunList.Height + ScaleY(8);
```

[image]