# Access the properties of check box control on Inno Setup "finish" page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In my Inno Setup project, I have some file in the `[Run]` section with flag `postinstall`, so Inno Setup creates a check box for this file in "finished" page. And now my question is, how to access properties of this check box  (like `Left`, `Right`, `Name`,...)  in `Code` section? I want to add some other component under this check box on run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkboxes on the "finished" page are not individual controls.

All checkboxes are just items in `WizardForm.RunList` of type [`TNewCheckListBox`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox).

For similar a question, see [Custom TLabel not displaying on FinishedPage in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60659791/3478652).